# OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82956 byte allocation with 30836 free bytes and 30KB until OOM?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

in my application i have a database where i store images but when i try to retrieve image in BitMap logcat shows OutOfMemoryError .this error does't appear when i retrieve only one image from the database(when i don't use do while loop my code is runing good ).please help i'm new in android.

this class try to retrieve images from db:

```
class Abc {

    ArrayList < ForBitMap > pic;

    Abc() {

        pic = new Abc < > ();

        DataBaseClass objOfDataBaseClass = new DataBaseClass(context);
        mCursor = objOfDataBaseClass.showData();

        if (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

            do {

                byte[] mg = null;

                mg = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mg, 0, mg.length);

                pic.add(new ForBitMap(bitmap));

            } while (mCursor.moveToFirst());

        }
    }
```

this class use for store the value in ArrayList(ArrayList pic;)

```
class ForBitMap{
    Bitmap btmp;

    ForBitMap(Bitmap btmp){
        this.btmp=btmp;
    }

}
```

logat status is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82956 byte allocation with 30836 free bytes and 30KB until OOM
```

Comment: try using largeHeap . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap

Comment: @SagarNayak when i use largeheep=true logcat shows same error

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: @SagarNayak same error OutOfMemoryError but previously  shows 30kb until oom and now showing 64kb until oom

Comment: @SagarNayak After largeheep=true: OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82956 byte allocation with 66236 free bytes and 64KB until OOM . before largeheep=true:   Failed to allocate a 82956 byte allocation with 30836 free bytes and 30KB until OOM?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't store bitmaps in database. Just store them in file storage and keep file path in database.

Comment: can u please give me a proper link on this topic

Comment: Sure, here is an example https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/Storing-image-URIs-using-Android-SQLite

Comment: And also you should use WeakReferences when you retrieve and use Bitmaps. It will prevent memory leaks (very often caused by Bitmaps)

Answer (score 0):

Try using LruCache for saving images, bitmap allocates memory every any bitmap is loaded evem if it was loaded previously. Using LruCache it will save your image with a key in cache memory itself.

Refer this link: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html